# I can't install Lubuntu 18.04.2 alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, lubuntu, acer

I've an Acer Apire One KAV60, that one with Android-Windows 7 dual-boot.

Now it runs (or walks) Windows 10. To make it faster, I'm planning to install Lubuntu alongside Windows, but the only option that appears is erase the full drive.

I've reinstalled Windows 10, but it's still hidden for Lubuntu, can be Android the problem?

I've this issue, the installation wizard shows me this:

[image: During Installation]

But GParted shows me this:

[image: GParted]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the PQServive partition to restore de laptop. The number of tartitions was too much for the wizard and it couldn't identify windows. Deleting the PQService partition solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into windows and go to disk management

Select the disk > right click > select shrink volume option

You will be able to see the new space when installing Ubuntu.